# Как сортировать DataGridView программно

Tags: c#, сортировка, datagridview

Ребят, подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать или что можно использовать. Мне нужно отсортировывать столбцы таблицы dataGridView, но проблема в том, что стандартная встроенная сортировка мне не подходит, у меня есть столбцы (на скриншоте столбец Position), который нужно сортировать не по алфавиту, а по определенной логике, есть столбцы (на скриншоте столбец Value), где помимо самого числа есть символ и в целом, это строка, а надо отсортировать как число и столбцы с картинками (на скриншоте цветные кружочки/флаги/логотипы). Саму логику сортировки я могу сделать. Я не могу найти информацию как правильно это сделать в DataGridView, можно ли как-то выгрузить всю текущую таблицу в двумерный массив или список, отфильтровать как надо и засунуть обратно? Можно ли менять порядок строк в таблице и если да, то как лучше это делать? Если кто сможет помочь, буду очень благодарен
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я нашел ответ, для этого можно воспользоваться интерфейсом `IComparer`. Для начала необходимо для всех нужных столбцов изменить свойство `DataGridViewColumnSortMode` на режим `Programmatic`. После под каждый столбец написать свой собственный класс сортировки наследуемый от `IComparer`.

Полезные советы по этой теме можно найти по ссылкам:

- [Установка режимов сортировки для столбцов элемента управления DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/column-sort-modes-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)
- [Метод DataGridView.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sort)
- [Интерфейс IComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer)
- [Метод IComparer.Compare(Object, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer.compare)